# Mi funcion de Javascript no se activa

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bueno, mi problema es que quiero activar una acción en una etiqueta , pero me marca un error y no se porque si todo esta como debería funcionar.

Etiqueta

```
 <a onclick="can();">Cancelar</a>
```

Funcion de .js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function can() {
alert("Hola mundo");
 } 


</script>
```

El error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando sobre el lenguaje de programación "Ruby on Rails" y el .js esta dentro de mi archivo .html.erb que es donde tengo mi formulario.

Comment: Podrias indicarnos que hay en la linea 107? seria lo que indica el primer error, la respuesta del usuario de mas abajo no es correcta, el punto y coma no esta relacionado.

Comment: ya descubrí mi error, gracias a esa linea, la actualizare

Comment: @MaxDominguez si no es correcta

Comment: Gracias por eliminar la respuesta incorrecta. @David podrias postear tu solucion como respuesta correcta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución a mi problema es que tenia mi función

```
 function can() {
alert("Hola mundo");
 }
```

Pero ademas tenia otra función de la siguiente forma

```
function cancel{
alert("adios mundo");
}
```

En la segunda función no había puesto los dos paréntesis necesarios, aunque esta estaba debajo de mi primer función, cuando llegaba a ese error me sacaba de mi script y por ende me deci que no reconocía la primera función.

Comment: marca la como resuelta tu pregunta